# Problem with underlining text using box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I need to underline some words in a heading. I have the following code from this excellent article: https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/

I'm using two box-shadows to create a 1px underline.

```
.underline {
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 calc(-0.2em + 1px) rgb(255, 255, 255),
        inset 0 -0.2em rgb(0, 0, 0);
}



<h1>I can help you <span class="underline">create positive impact.</span></h1>
```

It works fine. Apart from on an iPhone there is sub-pixel grey border around the edge of the white inset box shadow. As if the white box is not quite covering the black box. See screen grab:

[image]

I note that the code provided on CSS Tricks website includes

```
.underline {
  background-size: 1px 1em;
  display: inline;
}
```

I've also tried with this additional code, but it doesn't make any difference. (I think this code is superflous. It doesn't do anything?).

So... how do I stop this grey outline from displaying?

I've tried adding a shadow to the outside bottom edge of the box. To 'mask' the grey line, but it has not worked:

```
.underline {
    box-shadow:
        0 2px rgb(255, 255, 255),
        inset 0 calc(-0.2em + 1px) rgb(255, 255, 255),
        inset 0 -0.2em rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209930) in iOS.

For workaround, you can simply put an mask as overlay:

> -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);

```
    .underline {
        -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
        box-shadow:
            inset 0 calc(-0.2em + 1px) rgb(255, 255, 255),
            inset 0 -0.2em rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: I copied your code and tried locally, inspector in chrome to choose iPhone, and with the webkit addition it no longer appeared, I wonder why you would get different results